# Why was Buffy's test result positive?

Tags: comics, buffy-the-vampire-slayer

On page 24 of issue #5 of *Buffy the Vampire Slayer* Season 9, we see a

> pregnancy

test with a positive result.  However, later in issue #7, we learn that Buffy is

> a robot.

How could this be the case?  Could the original

> Buffybot

even perform the physical action required to take this test?

Comment: This question is REALLY hard to answer without using some terminology or describing some situations that really don't seem accepted on this site.

Comment: Rolled back the edits. This was deliberately phrased as it is to avoid spoilers.

Answer (score 12):

The original duplicate was intended to be a 'special' toy for Spike.  He wanted to vent his frustrations (in several forms) and was presumably capable of a wide range of activities.

Spike is hundreds of years old, and has likely explored many facets of sexuality (given that humans invariably acclimate to many different stimuli, and studies have shown that this is one facet of behavior where acclimation is possible).

It's therefore not surprising that 'she' would be capable of such an action.  Spike could easily have many reasons to want the robot to be capable of this, given his complicated and evolving feelings towards Buffy.  He could have wanted the ability to terrify her, and see the expected physical responses.

In short, there is no in-universe answer outside of "apparently, yes, she can and does urinate because she must have to take the test," but it is not unreasonable to assume it would have been a 'feature' of the original.

As to how the test was able to read as positive, that is harder to determine.  Modern tests (such as the one used) [test for the presence of hCG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pregnancy_test#Modern_tests), a hormone found in human blood and urine after implantation.

We can only assume that in their attempts to make the Buffybot more realistic and able to fool more and more types of examinations, they accidentally caused her blood/urine analogs to contain a protien sufficiently similar to hCG that it triggered the reaction on the test.

Comment: +1 because this answer is not only reasonable, but somehow still polite.  A neat trick.

Comment: @Tynam: It wasn't easy, I'll tell you.

Comment: Also, considering Warren made the Buffybot and he was a misogynist that only saw women as being good for limited functions, it would be pretty surprising for him not to incorporate those functions into his creations.

Comment: I don't feel this answers the question.  The question isn't why did she take the test, but why was the test _positive_?

Comment: @Tim: Check the edit history of the question.  Until ~24 hours ago, the question didn't ask how the test result could be positive, it asked how the robot could even take the test.  Valorum altered the question at roughly the same time they provided their answer.

Comment: Rather than re-ask what would essentially be a duplicate, I've *widened* the question to include the mechanism **and** the result.

Answer (score 11):

In-universe, Andrew speculates that there's some kind of issue with the Buffybot's "trueblood", that **her inability to metabolise food properly may have altered her blood pH, creating a false positive on the test.**

[image]
<sub><sup>[**Buffy: Season 9 - #09**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buffy_the_Vampire_Slayer_Season_Nine#Single_issues)</sup></sub>

And yes, I'm fully aware that that's **not how pregnancy tests work**.

---

On the question of the mechanics of how the Buffybot is able to urinate at all, that's down to the fact that she was designed by Andrew to effectively replicate the functions of a human. That evidently includes eating and pooping (but not menstruating, which is what prompted her to do the test in the first place).

[image]

Comment: This doesn't answer the question of how Buffy could have taken the test, though.  The test was a standard urine analysis test, not a blood test.

Comment: @Jeff - I assume her trueblood was mixing with her ingested foods to generate power, replicate bodily fluids, etc. She has a functioning metabolism, just not one that works well.